# Creating two QPainters in paintEvent

Tags: c++, qt, warnings

This is the small case of main program:

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
    QPainter *painter1 = new QPainter(this);
    QPainter *painter2 = new QPainter(this);

    delete painter1;

    painter2->drawLine(50,50,200,100);     
}
```

It is crashing. If remove the last line I get this warning message:

> QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

Answer (score 2):

The `QPainter` object is associated with a `QPaintDevice`.  In the notes on the third link below it talks about the life of a `QPainter` object in the context of `QWidget::paintEvent()`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/paintsystem.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#QPainter-2 (the third link)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a little bit that *phyatt* says, in order to avoid that error you should add to your code:

```
painter2->end();
```

After drawing the line. 
I have not tested yet, but I think adding that line of code is going to help you.